# Rose tree deconstructor

Tags: haskell

If we have a rose tree definition as follows:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
```

then I know that :> is an infix constructor. But how do you work with elements of such a tree? How can you traverse it to visit nodes or extract subtrees or elements?

Answer (score 7):

You can pattern match on the constructor like this (for example):

```
find :: (Eq a) => a -> Rose a -> Bool
find item (top :> rest)
  | item == top = True
  | otherwise = any (find item) rest
```

Addressing your second problem: Yes you can do this without any further knowledge of functors, but it would make sense to create a functor instance because it would make your datastructure more flexible. But lets get down to business: A `map` which processes every node would look something like this:

```
myMap :: (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b
myMap f (node :> rest) = f node :> map (myMap f) rest
```

This is pretty easy to add to the functor typeclass, because it does exactly what we want:

```
instance Functor Rose where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b
  fmap = myMap
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to visit each node recursively and process it, not just establish the existence of a node. Can this be done without having recourse to functors and monoids and foldables and so on?

Comment: @andro You effectively write a functor instance if you do that, whether or not you call it a functor in the end is irrelevant (well, you make it less usable and more opaque if you don't, but that's your decision).

Answer (score 1):

```
subtrees :: Rose a -> [Rose a]
subtrees (_ :> rs) = rs

label :: Rose a -> a
label (a :> _) = a
```